# Buffon's needle question - deriving an inequality with random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding part (i) of this question. How would one derive such an inequality and draw a sample space for such a problem? I know there is a sin function involved (not sure why exactly though) but I'm just finding it difficult having never dealt with geometric probability before. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help:

[image]

When the needle is inclined at an angle $x$ with respect to the horizontal, with $x$ satisfying $sin(x)=\frac{2y}{l}$, then the lower end of the needle just touches the table line. For the needle to cross it, we need $sin(x)\ge\frac{2y}{l}$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Hey why is it 2y / l? Shouldn't it just be sin(x) = y / l?

Comment: The hypotenuse is of length $\frac{l}{2}$